# Python typing with with types that may not be imported

Tags: python, python-typing

While we wait for numpy to implement typing, I want to create a simple typing object to indicate that a variable is either a numpy `ndarray` or tensorflow tensor.  How do I do this?  I want something like

```
X = Union[np.ndarray, tf.Tensor]
```

Ideally, I would be able to define this type even if I don't import tensorflow.  If I have to just use a placeholder type, that would be acceptable.  If I go that route, how can I do it?  Is there something like:

```
X = typing.PlaceholderType('X')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always pass a simple string instead of an actual object:

```
X = Union[np.ndarray, 'tf.Tensor']
```

This is only necessarily temporarily (I use the term loosely), until the release of Python 4.0, at which time function annotations will not be evaluated, but only saved as strings until someone at runtime wants to explicitly evaluate them.

Comment: Thanks!  How is the person evaluating the type going to know where `tf` is?  Will I have to put something like `if TYPE_CHECKING: import tensorflow as tf`?  (That would be fine.)